# Перемещение курсора в определенное положение строки ввода

Tags: jquery, ajax

Коллеги здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой, повешал на поле ввода номера маску, но курсор ввода при нажатии возникает в точке нажатия, а по хорошему нужно что бы он был вначале. Нашел некий код:

```
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
      if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
      } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
      }
  });
  return this;
  };

  $("#phone").setCursorPosition(3);
```

но он почему то не отрабатывает, подскажите где я совершил ошибку?

Вот наглядный пример:

```js
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  this.each(function(index, elem) {
      if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
      elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
      } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
      }
  });
  return this;
  };


  $("#phone").setCursorPosition(3);


$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#phone").mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form class="obratnuj-zvonok" autocomplete="off" action='email.php' method='post'>
<div class="form-zvonok">   
    <label>Номер телефона (с кодом) <span>*</span></label>
    <input type='text' id="phone"name='usernumber' required></div>
  
</form>
```

Comment: В примере всё работает же

Comment: У меня не работает. Браузер хром. Тыкаю на окно ввода и курсор ставится в середину, а должен в начало, по идее вообще не должно быть возможности поставить курсор в середину или в конец, всегда в начало должен перемещаться(на третью позицию). Там где код брал, там был пример, там все нормально работало.

Comment: А у вас какой-либо другой JS-код на странице отрабатывает? Может, где ошибка и у вас вообще все ваши скрипты не работают? Всякое бывает... отсюда можно только гадать

Comment: Да, отрабатывают, сама маска это ведь тоже скрипт и она отлично работает. Ну и в примере ведь тоже не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Долго долго тыкал, в итоге вот что натыкал:

```js
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
    if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
      $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    } else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
      var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd('character', pos);
      range.moveStart('character', pos);
      range.select();
    }
  };
  $('input[name="usernumber"]').click(function(){
    $(this).setCursorPosition(3);  
  });


$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#phone").mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form class="obratnuj-zvonok" autocomplete="off" action='email.php' method='post'>
<div class="form-zvonok">   
    <label>Номер телефона (с кодом) <span>*</span></label>
    <input type='text' id="phone"name='usernumber' required></div>
  
</form>
```